# Choke Placement for POE top or bottom?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, common-mode-choke

a colleague designed the pcb and I wanted to remove the bottom components and place them on top so that we may attach a flex pcb to the back side.

Attached is an image of the L3 choke, is there a particular reason to have placed it on the back of the board as there was a bunch of room ontop? Is there any issue reversing the placement side of this component?
[image]

Comment: Need to know frequencies and type of signal this is to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how it's a power filter, probably not. Since you are already adding impedance putting in a few vias will only increase inductance and probably make the filter better.

One reason to not do this is if you think there will be capactiive coupling to traces\components on the top of the board or radiation.

Another reason to not do this is that adding vias would be a problem for your circuit.

Another is room, if you don't have room then leave it on the back side of the board.

Comment: Right, its a POE circuit so I am replacing the connections with ferrites on the top side. The choke design and Ferrite design both work previously.